# Split strings into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a string (which represents a folder path).
The max number of levels is known (subsubfolder)
The min number of levels is known (root does not contain files).
The foldernames can contain spaces. 
There is no indication whether a in the example is a folder or a file.............
I want that string to be split into columns.

```
CREATE TABLE TESTDATA([path] [nvarchar](max))
INSERT INTO TESTDATA (path) VALUES (N'/a/)
INSERT INTO TESTDATA (path) VALUES (N'/a/ab/filename1)
INSERT INTO TESTDATA (path) VALUES (N'/a/ab/abc/filename2)
INSERT INTO TESTDATA (path) VALUES (N'/a/ab/abc/filename3)
INSERT INTO TESTDATA (path) VALUES (N'/a/ab/abc/abcd/filename4)
INSERT INTO TESTDATA (path) VALUES (N'/a/ac/ac e/filename5)
```

TESTDATA now looks like

```
|----------path-----------------|
/a
/a/ab/filename1
/a/ab/abc/filename2
/a/ab/abc/filename3
/a/ab/abc/abcd/filename4
/a/ac/ac e/filename5
```

but I need it to look like

```
filename--|--root--|--folder--|--subfolder--|--subsubfolder--|
----------|--------|----------|-------------|----------------|
filename1-|---a----|----ab----|
filename2-|---a----|----ab----|-----abc-----|
filename3-|---a----|----ab----|-----abc-----|
filename4-|---a----|----ab----|-----abc-----|-------abcd-----|
filename5-|---a----|----ac----|-----ac e----|
```

How would I go about this?

I am thinking I should do something with `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX` but I tried a thousand things; never getting it right. It seems `SUBSTRING` stops searching in a string when that string contains spaces.

Comment: For testing: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e91eb/1

Comment: Regex could provide you some insight of splitting the string

Comment: Show one of those "thousand things" please.

Comment: What columns will you be storing these data in?

Comment: @tombom one of the thousand things          http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/28f37/9

Comment: @MikeSmithDev Actually, I do not care :p.     I want to build a grouped report based on the outcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING` is a good approach.  Remember that `CHARINDEX` can take a third parameter that specifies the starting point for searching.  Using this, you can find the second `/`,  and third `/`, and so forth.  One way to break down the problem is to use subqueries that build on each other and attack one small piece of the problem at a time.  Here is an example that decomposes the filenames into subsub folder level using successive Common-Table Expressions:

```
with root as (
  select
    path,
    left(path, charindex('/', path, 2) - 1) as root,
    substring(path, charindex('/', path, 2), 1000) as rest
  from testdata
), folder as (
  select
    path,
    root,
    case when charindex('/', rest, 2) > 0
      then left(rest, charindex('/', rest, 2) - 1)
      else '' 
    end as folder,
    case when charindex('/', rest, 2) > 0
      then substring(rest, charindex('/', rest, 2), 1000)
      else rest
    end as rest
  from root
), subfolder as (
  select
    path,
    root,
    folder,
    case when charindex('/', rest, 2) > 0
      then left(rest, charindex('/', rest, 2) - 1)
      else '' 
    end as subfolder,
    case when charindex('/', rest, 2) > 0
      then substring(rest, charindex('/', rest, 2), 1000)
      else rest
    end as rest
  from folder
), subsubfolder as (
  select
    path,
    root,
    folder,
    subfolder,
    case when charindex('/', rest, 2) > 0
      then left(rest, charindex('/', rest, 2) - 1)
      else '' 
    end as subsubfolder,
    case when charindex('/', rest, 2) > 0
      then substring(rest, charindex('/', rest, 2), 1000)
      else rest
    end as rest
  from subfolder
)
select
  path,
  rest as filename,
  root,
  folder,
  subfolder,
  subsubfolder
from subsubfolder;
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e91eb/36

Sample Output:

```
PATH                      FILENAME    ROOT  FOLDER  SUBFOLDER  SUBSUBFOLDER
------------------------  ----------  ----  ------  ---------  ------------  
/a/                       /           /a               
/a/ab/filename1           /filename1  /a    /ab          
/a/ab/abc/filename2       /filename2  /a    /ab     /abc     
/a/ab/abc/filename3       /filename3  /a    /ab     /abc     
/a/ab/abc/abcd/filename4  /filename4  /a    /ab     /abc       /abcd
/a/ac/ac e/filename5      /filename5  /a    /ac     /ac e
```

**Note:** Removing the `/` that I've kept in as part of the folder name can be trivially done with `SUBSTRING(part, 2, 1000)` or `SUBSTITUTE(part, '/', '')`.

Comment: You tha master!!! Thanks! I understand what you do and it is actually pretty smart to do it like that. I will be using this technique more often!

Comment: @Henrov then why did you accept the answer without any code and that vaguely talked about a more complicated approach?

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand That was a mistake. I thought both of them pointed me in the right direction so wanted to thank 'em both. When I came back, I saw that didn't work. So I corrected it. mellamokb deserved it, his answer was perfect!

Answer (score 1):

I can point you to a direction (couldn't had time to write a solution).

Since the level of nesting is known, you can count the number of back-slashes (aka level of nesting) and have a CASE to handle each scenario. Then in each CASE block, get the deepest level of folder and update the table. You can have a UDF so that you can call it for each INSERT.

The assumption is that filenames are unique.